# создание Dll для структуры DateTime

Tags: c++, dll, datetime

Доброго времени суток. Необходимо реализовать dll библиотеку, выводящую определенные поля структуры DateTime.

**Хэдер:**

```
    using namespace std;
using namespace System;

class  Myclass {
    public: 
        static __declspec(dllexport) void PrintSeconds(DateTime date);
    };
```

**cpp:**

```
#include "iostream"
#include "windows.h"
#include "Dll2h.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace System;

 void Myclass::PrintSeconds(DateTime data)
{
    /* int nt;
     nt = data.Second;
     cout << nt << endl;*/
}
```

Во время сборки возникает ошибка С3395

> Ошибка    C3395   Myclass::PrintSeconds: __declspec(dllexport) невозможно
>   применять к функции с соглашением вызова __clrcall

Если из входных параметров функции убрать *DateTime data*, то все собирается.

Подскажите, как быть?  Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

Не стоит путать C++ и C++/сli. Для экспортирования из managed библиотеки следует пометить класс как public.

```
public ref class Myclass {
```